# Send on Behalf Not Working for Exchange 2003 SP2

Tags: exchange-2003

I have set up an new mailbox in Exchange 2003 SP2 / AD and given 'Full Mailbox Access' under Mailbox rights in the Exchange Advanced Tab to another user.  I also gave send of behalf permissions on under Delivery Options under the Exchange General Tab.  I then added that mailbox to the user's profile via Mail under Control Panel and added the mailbox in outlook.

But when I go send an email from the new email address it doesn't work, I get a permission denied reply for the 'System Administrator' account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the account has to be in the GAL.  So I forced an update of the GAL by going to Offline Address Lists in the Exchange System Manager, right clicking Default Address List, and Rebuild.  I then re-downloaded the address book via Send/Recieve in Outlook, and the send of behalf worked right after that.